# Spring Data JPA loads one to one relationship in two queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have following classes:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
public class UserIdentity implements UserDetails {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String facebookId;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private Timestamp unblockDate;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  private Role role;

  }

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToMany
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @JoinTable(name = "role_permission", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private List<Permission> permissions;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission")
public class Permission {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

And when I'm querying for user identity I can see these two queries generated in log:

```
Hibernate: select useridenti0_.id as id1_3_, useridenti0_.facebook_id as facebook2_3_, useridenti0_.password as password3_3_, useridenti0_.phone_number as phone_nu4_3_, useridenti0_.role_id as role_id7_3_, useridenti0_.unblock_date as unblock_5_3_, useridenti0_.username as username6_3_ from user_info useridenti0_ where useridenti0_.facebook_id=?
Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_1_0_, role0_.name as name2_1_0_, permission1_.role_id as role_id1_2_1_, permission2_.id as permissi2_2_1_, permission2_.id as id1_0_2_, permission2_.name as name2_0_2_ from role role0_ left outer join role_permission permission1_ on role0_.id=permission1_.role_id left outer join permission permission2_ on permission1_.permission_id=permission2_.id where role0_.id=?
```

But I expect to see only one query. Can you please help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I'm using CrudRepositor:

```java
public interface UserIdentityRepository extends CrudRepository<UserIdentity, Long> {
  UserIdentity findByFacebookId(String facebookId);
  UserIdentity findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

and I noticed following thing - if I search using method *findById()* it works as expected, but if I use *findByPhoneNumber()* then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FetchType` you are specifying on your entities is only used when using methods on the `EntityManager` that don't take any kind of query. 
This is what you are effectively doing when calling `findById()`.

But if you specify a query as Spring Data does for you when you use a query method as `findByPhoneNumber()` that query is used to determine the fetch strategy.

But you can control that by specifying an entity graph. You'd add an `@NamedEntityGraph` annotation to your entity class. And an `@EntityGraph` annotation to your query method referencing that named entity graph.

I have prepared [a simple example over at Github](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow-jpa/tree/master/src/test/java/de/schauderhaft/stackoverflow/fetchtuning)

I used the trivial entity graph

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "joined", includeAllAttributes = true)
```

It fetches everything eagerly, which might actually be what you want.

Comment: I tried your approach and it fixed issue for role. But I got new issue with permissions because I have relation many-to-many with roles.

Comment: You can tune your EntityGraph to specify the fetch strategy you want. If that doesn't work for your, it would be a good new question.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have one query.. and it would only load the `UserIdentity` in your case is to set the relationship as LAZY:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

and then load it upon first usage in a transactional method.

If it meets your logical design you could make the Role.id a primary key and also a foreign key and use `@MapsId` as described in this article: [link](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)